# How do I target a new browser window en ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**This is what I want:** Let's say I have a textbox and a button on a page. when I click the button, I get a page in a new browser window where I can make some choices. when I click OK on that new window, it disappears and my choice appears in the **textbox** located in the first window.

How do I do that in ASP.NET MVC?

I know that what I'm trying to do can be easily obtained through JavaScript. However, I'd like to apply the unobtrusive principle. So, I'll do first without JQuery in mind then, later, add JQuery.

**EDIT**

I remember with Yahoo Classic when you click "Contacts" button, a new window appears. On that window you have contacts with check boxes next to each contact. You check all the contacts you want to send the email to. When you click ok, the contacts window disappear and all the contacts appears in the Send to **TextBox** located in the first window.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Yahoo Classic would have used javascript for that functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really, the initial page could be set to refresh periodically and once the choices have been made and submitted to your MVC the next refresh would cause the page to pick up the new data other than that, without Javascript I don't believe it's possible.

***EDIT***

Thinking about this some more and following some of the comments there is another approach to be taken. If the desire is for a graceful degradation if javascript is disabled then the default mode of operation should be:

- User clicks the button
- The browser loads the child page in the same window (no new browser window)
- They make their selection and then click to submit those responses
- The browser loads the parent page and the results displayed

If javascript is available then the first stage would be to change the click event to now spawn the child window and in the child window change the submit to return the selections to the parent window which then uses those to update the display. With JQuery as well you'd have the ability to do this even slicker, i.e. an overlay loading the child page so you don't even leave the browser window.

Comment: That's true.. And even making the original page refresh repeatedly, after you clicked the button - you'll have to use javascript to do this.

Comment: @Richard77, I'd be really surprised if that was achieved without using javascript to process the return info from a window.open call.

Comment: @artiom-chilaru, not so. The data from the child page would be submitted directly back to the application and then retrieved when the page refreshes from the application (refresh doesn't need javascript). The other issue I missed was that the closing of the child window would require javascript.

Comment: Guys, I'm lost. Is it feasible or not? If that's the case, I'm ok with that. At least, I know that this solution is out of my list. I'll try something else or just use Javascript (But, how about if Javascript is disabled?... Ah?)

Comment: @richard77 This is really only feasible if you use javascript. How many of your users really have javascript turned off??

Comment: @Richard77, @Ryan is correct. If you read my EDIT above you'll see how it would have to be to work without javascript and that should be the base on which you build your javascript & JQuery enhancements if you want a fully degradable site.

Comment: @Ryan: I thank you for the answer. You know, newbies, like me,tend to listen to what experienced developers say. Please, follow this link and will get to a question I asked a few months ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491239/what-happens-to-my-web-application-if-javascript-is-disabled